# What might be good textbooks for the mathematics behind Machine Learning?

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

I am currently studying Linear Algebra and I have taken Calculus 1, 2, and 3, as well as Differential Equations. Can someone please provide guidance on what material I should study next in order to continue developing my Machine Learning Skills? I am programming mainly in Python, and in R. I have a book on machine learning but it just glosses over the functions and calculating the gradient descent functions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that should be enough to work through a decent ML book, assuming you know statistics.

Comment: Here’s a popular book which has its first edition free to download- https://www.statlearning.com/

Comment: Here’s a book I like from a course I took, which currently has its videos accessible online- http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~magdon/courses/ONLINElearn.php